# GWT button clicks getting laggy very quickly using Places/Activities in GWT2.1

Tags: gwt, android-activity, gwt2

i'm new to GWT2.1's Places and Activities.

I'm using the same ActivityMapper as example below and getting laggy button clicks after just a few navigations.

The MVP architecture I'm using has the Presenter create listeners and define the View interface, but View objects are singletons.

Is my problem with lag due to all the listeners building up exponentially?  Should I change it so that the View creates all the listeners instead? Or should I try [unbinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626742/unbinding-presenters-necessary-in-gwt) instead?

E.g. in the GWT2.1 example [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html#Activities) a new Activity is created every time `getActivity(Place)` is called.

```
public Activity getActivity(Place place) {
    if (place instanceof HelloPlace)
        return new HelloActivity((HelloPlace) place, clientFactory);
    else if (place instanceof GoodbyePlace)
        return new GoodbyeActivity((GoodbyePlace) place, clientFactory);
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I changed the MVP architecture to the same as the example [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html#Views) with View defining Activity and ViewImpl containing the UI Handlers.  Since the Activities no longer contain handlers and the ViewImpls are singletons the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

The [view here](http://code.google.com/intl/en/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html#Views) adds event handlers to its widgets. It later calls its presenter when appropiate. I don't think that unbindinding the events would free up much memory or speed up the browser's event queue.

I believe you should further investigate if the actual button click is slow, or if it's the creation of Activities happening upon the event, or whatever else.

Comment: My application doesn't do that (The MVP architecture I'm using has the Presenter create listeners and define the View interface, but View objects are singletons). I'm not sure if I should restructure my Views in case the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Try unbinding the presenters then. I know it's very difficult to trace things like garbage collection in the browser, but maybe you can hunt down the problem with chrome's profiling console or the speedtracer.